# Cyclic modules over local rings

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative local ring. Is it true that all cyclic $R$-modules  are indecomposable? If not please give me an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed its true. Let $R$ be a (not necessary commutative) local ring and $M$ a cyclic right $R$-module. 
There is a right ideal $I$ such that $M\cong \frac RI$. Now suppose 
we can decompose $M$ into two proper submodules, then there are proper right ideals $A$, $B$ containing 
$I$ such that $\frac RI = \frac AI\oplus\frac BI$. This means that
$R = A + B$. But since $R$ is local and $A$, $B$ are proper 
we have $A, B \subseteq J(R)$ and 
therefore $A + B \subseteq J(R)$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

A cyclic module $M$ would have to be a homomorphic image of $R$, and so by correspondence it has a unique maximum submodule.

This maximum submodule contains all proper submodules... so how would you get two proper submodules to add up to $M$?